Heat equation with periodic BC using complex Fourier series.
$k>0,$
$\begin{cases}
{u_t = ku_{xx}}, -\pi \le x \le \pi, t>0\\
{u(x,0)=f(x)}\\ 
u(-\pi,t)=u(\pi,t), u_x(-\pi,t)=u_x(\pi,t), t>0
\end{cases}$
I want to solve this heat equation using complex Fourier series.
Let $f(x) = \sum_{n=-{\infty}}^{\infty} c_ne^{inx}$ where $c_n = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi} ^{\pi} f(x)e^{-inx}dx$
Since $u_{xx}(x,0) = \sum_{n=-{\infty}}^{\infty} c_ne^{inx}(-n^2)$
(I know it is somewhat weird, but I remind of the separation of variables.)
Let $u_{xx}(x,t) = \sum_{n=-{\infty}}^{\infty} c_ne^{inx}(-n^2)\phi_n(t). $
Now I am stucked. What should I do? I think something is wrong, but I don't know what to do...

$$u(x,t)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} c_n\cdot e^{-n^2 k t}\cdot e^{i n x}$$

By separation of variables you need to find functions $T_n$ such that $T_n(t)e^{inx}$ will solve the heat equation. As @gpmath suggested, you will get $T_n(t)=c_ne^{-n^2kt}$
